# Combine 0th index of one array to 0th index another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP. and I want to combine two arrays from 0th index
e.g.

```php
$a = [7, 5, 6, 9]
$b = [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

result should be

```
$c = ["7-1", "5-3", "6-2", "9-4"];
```

Comment: I feel inclined to ask ... *why?* I just have a niggling suspicion that whatever you're doing might not be the best way of doing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `foreach` loop, and put them together. This of course expects that there are at least as many elements in `$b` as there are in `$a`.

```php
$a = [7, 5, 6, 9];
$b = [1, 3, 2, 4];
$result = [];

foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {
    $result[] = $value.'-'$b[$key];
}
```

If for some reason your array isn't numerically indexed, you can use `array_values()` to extract the values only (thus getting a numerically indexed array).

If you expect that `$b` can be shorter than `$a`, you can stop at the last iteration of `$b` by checking if that element exists by doing..

```php
$a = [7, 5, 6, 9];
$b = [1, 3, 2, 4];
$result = [];

foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {
    if (!isset($b[$key])) {
        break;
    }
    $result[] = $value.'-'$b[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one-liner,

```
$result = array_map(function($a1,$b1){ return $a1.'-'.$b1; },$a,$b);
```

array_map accept multiple arrays and simultaneously we can receive instance of each one.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oQXMR).

Comment: Thank you so much @Drakula Predator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_combine` with `array_walk`

```
$c = array_combine($a,$b);
$r = [];
array_walk($c, function($k,$v) use (&$r){$r[] = "{$v}-{$k}";});
print_r($r);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/fIJEs)